# Why is my GoogleMap leaking its parent ViewGroup?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My app is leaking the root layout of one of its activities every time that activity is destroyed.  Merging shortest paths to GC roots shows only one root for each leaked instance, and the path is all Google Maps API classes:

```
com.google.android.gms.location.internal.t @ 0x42387220 Native Stack
'- a com.google.android.gms.location.internal.s @ 0x42387268
   '- a com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.v @ 0x425f73a0
      '- c com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aj @ 0x4261f5d8
         '- i com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.a @ 0x425fbbf0
            '- d com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y @ 0x42754cd0
               '- mParent android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x4261f678
                  '- mParent android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x4245c6c0
                     '- mParent android.widget.RelativeLayout @ 0x4254ca08
```

I'm not using `FrameLayout` anywhere, so I assume that's part of the `MapFragment` UI.

What could I possibly be doing to cause this?  The activity doesn't do anything with the map except call `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` on it.  I'm not creating any markers or anything.

This is how the fragment is declared in the activity XML:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/fake_status_bar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftButtons"
    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
```

I'm using google-play-services_lib version 26, which is the latest.

**Edit:** This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8111).

Comment: It's quite possibly a bug in whatever `com.google.android.gms.location.internal.t` is. If you can reproduce it with a simple sample, file an issue... um, wherever Play Services issues get filed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Turns out it does not occur if I don't call `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.  Awesome, Google.  Just awesome.